# java mail 1.4.5 on android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm developing a IMAP client on a custom Android device. So i decided to use the Java Mail library. 
I needed to update from the 1.4.1 version of Java Mail to 1.4.5 because i had memory problem in case of huge INBOX folder (About 120k mails).

So i downloaded the 2 jars (mail.jar and activation.jar) from the official home page, i tried also with the release candidate 1.4.6 but i cannot make it works.

Once i build the entire app, everything is ok, but when i run, here's what it comes:

```
2-05 17:31:21.020 19862 19912 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 571 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
12-05 17:31:21.030 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
12-05 17:31:21.030 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
12-05 17:31:21.030 19862 19912 I dalvikvm: Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 571 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
12-05 17:31:21.030 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
12-05 17:31:21.030 19862 19912 E dalvikvm: Could not find method javax.activation.DataHandler.getName, referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding
12-05 17:31:21.030 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4632: Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;.getName ()Ljava/lang/String;
12-05 17:31:21.040 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
12-05 17:31:21.040 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeUtility;.getEncoding (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)Ljava/lang/String;
12-05 17:31:21.040 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeUtility;
12-05 17:31:21.050 19862 19912 D EMAIL   : Releasing mail download wake lock
12-05 17:31:21.050 19862 19912 W dalvikvm: threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa30)
12-05 17:31:21.060 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime: Uncaught handler: thread pool-1-thread-1 exiting due to uncaught exception
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:130)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:685)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:636)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at it.kynetics.imwatch.email.imap.EmailAuthenticationImpl.login(EmailAuthenticationImpl.java:36)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at it.kynetics.imwatch.email.imap.EmailConnection.execute(EmailConnection.java:21)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at it.kynetics.imwatch.email.ImCloudEmailService$GetEmailTask.run(ImCloudEmailService.java:148)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
12-05 17:31:21.080 19862 19912 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
12-05 17:31:21.120  1830  1830 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 19862 SIG: 3
```

I tried checking the DataHandler and getName method in the jar, and everything is ok.

Is there anyone who had the same problem?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Not every java library works on Android. You can only use [javamail port for android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/). The latest versions of Javamail have still not been ported for Android

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I needed to modify the mail.jar and its source codes. It'a "import packaging" problem. In the Android porting, some of the mail.jar classes, import other classes from the additionnal.jar in which the package name is myjava.awt. exc. 
In java mail 1.4.5 that package is named java.awt exc, withouth the "my" prefix. Fixing that, all will work.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Do you have the javamail 1.5.3 ported to Android? Can you explain me how to port it?